# Find all integer solutions to $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, egyptian-fractions

> Find all integer solutions $(x, y)$ of the equation 
>   $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{3}$$

What have done is that: 
$$\frac{1}{x}= \frac{2y-3}{3y}$$
so, 
$$x=\frac{3y}{2y-3}$$
If $2y-3 = +1 \text{ or } {-1}$, $x$ will be an integer, so we choose integer $y$ 
to make $2y-3=1 \text{ or } {-1}$. $y = 2$ or $y = 1$ is such a solution.
Also, $2y - 3$ can be deleted by numerator $3$, so $2y - 3$ can be $3$ or $-3$ too. This gives $y = 3$ or $y = 0$, but $y$ can not be $0$. So far, we have $y=1,2,3$. Finally, $2y-3$ can be deleted by numerator $y$, but how can we find such a $y$?

Comment: Do you want to solve $2y - 3 = y$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another answer that does not follow your approach is like this:

Given integers $x,y$ such that $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{3}$:

$3x+3y = 2xy$.

Thus $4xy - 6x - 6y = 0$ and hence $(2x-3)(2y-3) = 9$.

Now it remains to find all factorizations of $9$ as a product of two integers.

Comment: wowow thanks great method

Comment: really elegant... very nice

Comment: @user329827: You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Your approach can be continued to a full solution. Let's see it in detail:

Given integers $x,y$ such that $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{3}$:

At least one of $x,y$ is positive, and by symmetry we can assume that $y$ is positive.

$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{2y-3}{3y}$.

Thus $x = \frac{3y}{2y-3} = 1 + \frac{y+3}{2y-3}$.

If $y > 6$ then $y+3 < 2y-3$ and so $0 < \frac{y+3}{2y-3} < 1$, which makes $x$ not an integer.

Thus $y \le 6$.

It only remains to check all $y$ from $1$ to $6$.

Comment: @user329827: See my other answer for another approach. It is more elegant but it only works in this special case, whereas this answer works for other kinds of diophantine problems too.

Comment: Although you don't give even a solution.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: I do not spoon-feed.

Comment: I think that you gave many logical feed,not me.It seemed that everyone ate your answer.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: In general I give the crucial logical insights, but I leave the actual work to the student to finish. In this case I left out: (1) why at least one of $x,y$ is positive; (2) the algebraic manipulation to obtain the first equation; (3) the computations to check all the possibilities at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If $0<x\le y$ then $\frac23 = \frac1x+\frac1y \le \frac1x+\frac1x$ and so $x\le3$.

If $x<0$ then $\frac23 < \frac1{-x}+\frac23=\frac1y$ and so $y=1$.

Therefore $(x,y) \in \{ (3,3) , (-3,1) , (1,-3), (2,6),(6,2)\}$.

Comment: in three to final , x>3 right ?

Comment: Sorry for mistake.

Comment: oh. good but is there possibility that x can be negative ..?

Comment: I fixed your logical errors and formatted your answer better, but you're missing solutions. The first two lines are now correct but you failed to find all the solutions and so your last line is wrong.

Comment: I forgot some solution, and your format is not big improvement.

Comment: You are very ungrateful. If you read your original answer: (1) its logical structure in the first case is terribly unclear; (2) you said "$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{y}$" for the second case, which is **completely false**; (3) you wrote "$(x,y) = (3,3)(-3,1)(1,-3)$" which is **simply invalid notation**. I'm only upvoting your answer because you fixed your mistaken conclusion.

Comment: I would glad if you formatted only grammar and latex.Even if answerer is low point user,you may not fix answer's style.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: If you don't like my edit, you are free to revert it as you wish. However, I am also free to vote as I wish. I think your method is a good alternative, but if you wish to degrade it back to a mathematically incorrect version, I'll have no choice but to downvote.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: I notice you still do not acknowledge that I fixed your **mathematically false** statement and that your original conclusion was **mathematically unacceptable** notation, which are the main reasons I edited your answer. It has **nothing to do with** your reputation.

Comment: That's wrong. You still don't understand.After I saw your answer,I wrote unlogical and another answer.My purpose was to write unlogical and visible answer.Because I thought your answer is complex.And I always don't write logical answer except logical problem.